# How to add custom javascript to Wordpress Admin using a plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I am setting up a new Wordpress plugin with a custom metabox. This box contains sets of fields that I store in an array. I want the user to be able to add a new set of fields by clicking a button on the admin-page.

I read different posts on how to accomplish this but I havent succeeded yet. For testing purposes I created a real simple setup in the metabox to change a text of a

element. This is also not working so I think it is a problem with loading the scripts correctly.

So what I did so far:
- add action through admin_enqueue_scripts
- register the script using wp_register_script
- enqueue script using wp_enqueue_script
- setup the js file (choose for testpurpose to store it in same dir as the plugin

```
function amai_woordjes_scripts() {

wp_register_script( 'amai_woordjes_updaten', 'amai_woordjes_updaten.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'amai_woordjes_updaten' );

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'amai_woordjes_scripts' );



//HTML code I use in the function which is called by add_meta_box

echo '<p id="demo">Current text</p>';
echo '<button id="woordje_toevoegen" onclick="woordjesToevoegen();">Woorden toevoegen</button>';


//amai_woordjes_updaten.js
<script>
  function woordjesToevoegen() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New texxt";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216879/how-to-enqueue-javascripts-in-a-plugin

Answer (score 2):

You need use function **wp_enque_script()**. You use incorrect script path.

```
plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . path/to/script.js
```

Comment: Thanx for your feedback. The wp_enque_script() was indeed a mistake i made while copying the code (didnt want to copy the whole thing). For the script-directory I changes the code according to your corrections: 

wp_register_script( 'amai_woordjes_updaten', plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'amai_woordjes_updaten.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

I double checked the script name and it is correct (it is in the same directory as the plugin at the moment for testing purposes). But still no luck. Is it possible to use javascript in a plugin in the admin-area?

Comment: Use __DIR__ instead DIR and you can see in dev tools 404 error if you path incorrect

Comment: Yeah i used ```( __DIR__ )``` but Stackoverflow changed it to a bold text like your comment Max. I am indeed getting the 404 error though in DEV tools. So I echoed the plugin location and checked it a couple of times. But I am sure the location is correct.

Comment: If you path really right maybe you need change permission to files. Set 644 to you files

Comment: I think the problem is that it is refering to the actual location of the script. In my case this is '/home/wappdzy83/domains/wappdesign.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/amai-cpt-test/amai_woordjes_updaten.js'. But when I check the 404 error it is adding the websitename 'https://wappdesign.nl/home/wappdzy83/domains/wappdesign.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/amai-cpt-test/amai_woordjes_updaten.js?ver=1.0'.

Comment: I got it working by directly referencing to the script, but off course that is not the most flexible integration. I will do some additional testing.

Answer (score 2):

First You have to set the file path

Create js folder in your plugin root directory and move the 'amai_woordjes_updaten.js' file in js folder

```
function amai_woordjes_scripts() {

wp_register_script( 'amai_woordjes_updaten', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'js/amai_woordjes_updaten.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'amai_woordjes_updaten' );

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'amai_woordjes_scripts' );
```